# Can I move air return higher?

Tags: hvac, ducts

I need to install some open shelving but the brackets they use are at a height that would interfere with the air return pictured. Would it be okay to relocate the return 4” higher or is there a reason (Kentucky code) that dictates how much distance it should be from the ceiling? The ceiling is 9’ high and the air is returned between two studs that are open all the way to top plate. There is no actual ductwork.
[image]

Comment: When was the house built?  Where?  Where is the furnace relative to the duct?  Does the heat work well in the area served by the return?

Comment: Unscrew the grill and take a picture of the inside. You might be in for some duct work. If you're luck then it's just an empty wall cavity.

Comment: You might want to rig something up so when you cut the drywall all the dust doesn't end up in your "ductwork".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can move it up as long as the top plate does not restrict the air flow. I don't know where you are located but where I live there is no code against moving it.

Comment: I’m in KY USA. Thanks!